# Qual a origem de «proio»?

Tags: significado, etimologia, português-europeu, regionalismo

No norte de Portugal, mais precisamente no Minho é usada com bastante frequência a palavra «proio» com o significado que aparece no [aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/proio):

> proio s. m. || (Minho) (pop.) assento, traseiro.

Curiosamente não aparece em nenhum dicionário de Portugal como Porto Editora ou Priberam.

Mas qual é que é a origem desta palavra?

Comment: Será que tem a ver com a proa dos barcos (com o sentido ligeiramente alterado)?

Comment: @GabrielDiego poderá ser. Se quiser investigar...

Answer (score 2):

Etimologicamente, a palavra **proio** é de origem grega (grafia: *προιο* ou *προϊο*). Significa "pré", "prévio", "antes", "atrás" etc. É essa a mais plausível hipótese por que, na língua portuguesa, tal palavra foi semanticamente associada a palavras como "traseiro" e "assento".

Na Medicina, por exemplo, denomina-se **proiomenorreia** a menstruação que ocorre antes da hora (ciclo menstrual de menos de 28 dias). Todas as componentes morfológicas dessa palavra são gregas: **proio** (antes) + **meno** (menstruação) + **reia** (fluxo, fluir, escorrer) = proiomenorreia = menstruação que flui antes do momento previsto.